# SQL limit by an aggregate

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
table records {
   created :: datetime not null
   name :: text not null
   people :: number not null
}
```

and want to do a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT { SUM (people) < 200 }
```

So instead of limiting the result set to a fixed number, limit it so that if I were to `SUM(people)` it would be less than 200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a common table expression to compute a running total, assuming you are using Oracle or recent versions of SQL Server and Postgres.

```
select created, name, people, running_total from (
  select  created, name, people, sum(people) over(order by created) as running_total from records 
  ) r
where r.running_total<200
```

See a SQL Server version in action at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/07eae/15

It is probably more idiomatic to write these kind of expressions using a with clause, eg,

```
with running as 
  (select  created, name, people, sum(people) over(order by created) as
   running_total from records)
select * from running where running_total<200
```

Comment: It looks like your interpretation of the question is different than mine.

Comment: @Dan, yes, it does -- this was my assumtion (possibly, wrong), of what sum(people) meant. Perhaps Heptic could clarify.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. This is what i meant by SUM(people) :D

Comment: @Heptic, not at all, seems I understood you :D Have a look at PARTITION BY inside the window function too, which is similar to group by outside in a non-window clause.

Answer (score 1):

The having keyword works in most database engines.

```
select field1, count(*) records
from somewhere
where something
group by field1
having count(*) < 200
```

In at least one database engine (redbrick) you can use the word when instead of having.  Also, in at least one database engine (redbrick) you can use the alias in the having clause.

Another way is like this:

```
select *
from (
select field1, count(*) records
from somewhere
where something
group by field1
) derivedtable
where records < 200
```